# Project referencing wrong version of DLL

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, app-config

My project references Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll and I have included version 9.0.0.0 but when running the application I get the following error:

[image]

When stepping through the code and asking what version of the file is actually being used:

[image]

When looking at the file properties in VS:

[image]

I have tried looking for other copies of the dll on my system and deleting them but this hasn't helped.  I have also tried a bindingRedirect in the app.config:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      <codeBase version="9.0.0.0" href="file:///C:/DLLS/Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

In the output window when building:

[image]

It seems most people can get things to work, even if only as a test, when using a bindingRedirect.  What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the reference "Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll" from your references and install the nuget **Microsoft.CrmSdk.Workflow**

Comment: Updating the project to a higher version of .net framework and then installing the latest version of CRM SDK seemed to solve the issue for me.